# What is the divergence $\operatorname{div}u$ of a $L^2(\Omega)^d$ function $u$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open. In the book *Navier-Stokes Equations - Theory and Numerical Analysis* by *Roger Temam* the author is using the divergence $\operatorname{div}u$ of a $L^2(\Omega)^d$ function $u$ at the beginning of [subsection 1.2 (*A density theorem*)](https://books.google.de/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22The%20results%20of%20this%20section%20will%20allow%20us%20to%20give%20a%20characterization%20of%22&source=bl&ots=0pvKSVb3Oi&sig=G5DrSATU9-WL8Inli5Wgh8RrMIY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu-_e5gbvKAhUHDA8KHTSDC0AQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20results%20of%20this%20section%20will%20allow%20us%20to%20give%20a%20characterization%20of%22&f=false).

> What is meant?

I assume that either some kind of weak differentiability is meant or $\operatorname{div}$ is somehow extended to $L^2(\Omega)^d$. For example, I'm aware of the fact that we can extend the gradient $\nabla:C_0^\infty(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega;\mathbb R^d)$ to the Sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: It is intended that derivatives are taken in distributional sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the distributional divergence, that is for $v \in L^2(\Omega)$ we have $v = \operatorname{div}u$ iff
$$\int_\Omega v \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x = -\int_\Omega u \cdot \nabla \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x \quad\forall \varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega).$$
To be compared with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions.

Comment: Let me try to understand this: For $u\in C^1(\Omega;\mathbb R^d)$ and $K\subseteq\Omega$ compact with $\partial\Omega\in C^1$ we have $$\operatorname{div}(\varphi u)=\varphi\operatorname{div}u+u\cdot\nabla\varphi$$ and $$\int_K\operatorname{div}(\varphi u)\;{\rm d}λ=\int_{\partial K}\varphi u\cdot\nu\;{\rm d}o\;,$$ by Gauss's theorem, i.e. $$\int_K\varphi\operatorname{div}u\;{\rm d}λ=-\int_Ku\cdot\nabla\varphi\;{\rm d}λ$$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. So, your equation is satisfied by any smooth enough $v$, if $\Omega$ is bounded and $\partial\Omega$ is smooth enough.

Comment: That's the motivation, right? Can we show, that each $v\in L^2$ has a distributional divergence in that sense? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Yes, this is the motivation. Every $u \in L^2$ has a distributional divergence, but the divergence may not belong to $L^2$. You might want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative

Comment: Do you have a reference for a proof? I suppose we only need to have $v\in\mathcal L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$. Maybe you shouldn't state that $v\in L^2(\Omega)$ is the distributional divergence iff ...

Comment: A proof for what?

Comment: A scalar $L^2$-function doesn't need to be weakly differentiable. So, I would be surprised if each vector-valued $L^2$-function has a distributional divergence. If you've a reference for a proof, I would be happy.

Comment: Every $L^2$-function is a distribution and every distribution has a derivative, just by definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Derivatives_of_distributions.

Comment: If you define $\nabla\cdot u$ to be any element $v$ of $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ which satisfies your equation, is $v$ uniquely determined (in $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$)? It's clear that if $u$ is in $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ such that $u_i$ is weakly differentiable wrt the $i$-th variable, then $v=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}$ satisfies your equation.

Comment: Yes, $v$ is unique. If $v_2$ is a second function, you have $\int (v - v_2) \,  \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$.

Comment: @gerw, can we talk about some bounds of the form $\|\nabla\cdot 
 u\|\le C\|u\|$ ?

Comment: @Hirak: This is a very different question...

Comment: @gerw, Oh, ok. I thought there might be a similarity after all. Anyways, I have asked a separate [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314182/specific-bounds-on-divergence-operator-in-sobolev-setting) in MO regarding this. Will you kindly consider looking at it ?